# Combine the same rows into 1 database on Python

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I have database, I want combine the same rows into 1 row

Example:

```
Game   |   Creator  |   Year
________________________________
aaa    |   zzz      |   2002
________________________________
bbb    |   xxx      |   2001
________________________________
aaa    |   zzz      |   2000
________________________________
bbb    |   xxx      |   3001
```

I want get:

```
Game   |   Creator  |   Year    |
________________________________|
aaa    |   zzz      |   2002
       |            |___________|
       |            |   2000    | 
________________________________|
bbb    |   xxx      |   2001    |
       |            |___________|  
       |            |   3001    |
________________________________|
```

P.S. Don't combine column 'Year'

Comment: I don't think SQL can do this because SQL is row-based, so 1 record = 1 row. Maybe you should use `group by` to get the result like aaa | zzz | 2000, 2002. Or replace the duplicated  Game | Creator row with blank character. To get the result exactly like in the post Excel is the only tool I can think of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the question is unclear I'm assuming you are importing a Database into python and then doing the operations, I recommend using sqlite3 for doing these operations

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3

# connect to the database
data = sqlite3.connect('database_name.db')

# execute the SQL query and load the results into a pandas df
df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT Game, Creator, GROUP_CONCAT(Year, ', ') AS Years FROM table_name GROUP BY Game, Creator;", data)

print(df)
```

Comment: When I try compile this code, I have error: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT Game, Creator, GROUP_CONCAT(Year, ', ') AS Years FROM table GROUP BY Game, Creator;': near "table": syntax error

when I put "" it still doesn't work